# XNA - how to draw an object farther

Tags: c#, xna

Here's how I draw some shape defined by vertices not shown here.

```
        Vector3 position = (5,5,1);
        Matrix world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
        BasicEffect basicEffect = new BasicEffect(graphicsDevice);


        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, -20), new Vector3(0, 0, 100), Vector3.Up);
        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
                                                    graphics.Viewport.AspectRatio,
                                                    1.0f,
                                                    100);


        // Set BasicEffect parameters.
        basicEffect.World = world;
        basicEffect.View = view;
        basicEffect.Projection = projection;

        //....draw some shape with basicEffect
```

I would like to paint the same shape only farther away so that its center stays in the same (x,y) pixel on screen but it is overall smaller as it's more distant.

I've tried scaling the position vector but had no success with it:

```
                position .Z *= 2;
                position .X *= 2;
                position .Y *= 2;
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Think about it geometrically: moving the object away from the camera means moving it along a line defined by two points: the camera's position and the object's position.

Now it's easy!

1) Find the vector object-to-camera, i.e.

```
Vector3 direction = objectPosition - cameraPosition;
```

2) Move the object alongside that vector by a certain amount, that is:

2.1) Normalize the direction

```
direction.Normalize();
```

2.2) Move the object by an amount x in that direction

```
objectPosition += direction * x;
```

And there you have it.